# Is there any authority that says a federal case is considered final upon entry on the civil docket?

Tags: civil-law, civil-procedure

So I have a federal case where the decision was made on a Monday (let us call it January 19) but the order was not entered on the federal civil docket until Wednesday (January 21).  When is the case considered final as a matter of American law?  Any authority would be great.  9th Cir is best.  Anything Wright and Miller or Moore might have to say is also good but I simply cannot find anything.  A foreign court researched the matter and concluded that the date the decision was entered on the US Federal docket is irrelevant to determining when the case is considered final as a matter of American law.